# How to encrypt ASP.NET 4.0 Web.Config?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, web-config, asp.net-4.0

I'm new in ASP.NET and I'm making a WebSite that gets data from a database through an ODBC.

I've the connection string in the Web.Config and I don't like it. If someone gets the Web.Config they can get to the database.

Is it possible to encrypt this data?